# Android handle lifecycle event on Jetpack Compose Screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-lifecycle

In Jetpack Compose all screen are composable function. `Fragments` are not used in Jetpack Compose.

How we can handle lifecycle events with Jetpack Compose? If we use Fragment we can handle lifecycle event (`onStart/onPause/onResume/onStop`). Those are useful for difference scenario like releasing resource, stop observing changes etc.

In Jetpack Compose if i need to handle those event how can i do that in Composable Screen?

Please help me with some idea or resource so that i can understand this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is precisely the [example straight from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get LifecycleOwner
`val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current`

and register `LifecycleEventObserver` using `DisposableEffect` and remove this observer on onDispose function of `DisposableEffect`.

You can also use rememberUpdatedState if the functions you pass might change during recompositions.

I add a sample

```
@Composable
private fun DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle(
    onResume: () -> Unit,
    onPause: () -> Unit,
) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Safely update the current lambdas when a new one is provided
    val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle composition ENTER",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()

    val currentOnResume by rememberUpdatedState(onResume)
    val currentOnPause by rememberUpdatedState(onPause)

    // If `lifecycleOwner` changes, dispose and reset the effect
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        // Create an observer that triggers our remembered callbacks
        // for lifecycle events
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle ON_CREATE",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle ON_START",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                    currentOnResume()
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                    currentOnPause()
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle ON_STOP",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle ON_DESTROY",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                else -> {}
            }
        }

        // Add the observer to the lifecycle
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the observer
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)

            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle composition EXIT",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            )
                .show()
        }
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color(0xff03A9F4))) {
        Text(
            text = "Disposable Effect with lifecycle",
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}
```

Demonstration

```
val context = LocalContext.current

DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle(
    onResume = {
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle onResume()",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        )
            .show()
    },
    onPause = {
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "DisposableEffectWithLifeCycle onPause()",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        )
            .show()
    }

)
```

Answer (score 4):

Create Function

```
@Composable
fun ComposableLifecycle(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
    onEvent: (LifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit
) {

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
            onEvent(source, event)
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

Call this function inside the screen

```
 val TAG = "SecondScreen"
    ComposableLifecycle { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "On Start")
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "On Resume")
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "On Pause")
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "On Stop")
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "On Destroy")
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
```

Source - [Life Cycle In Jetpack Compose](https://medium.com/@mohammadjoumani/life-cycle-in-jetpack-compose-2e96136ab936)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be triggered after start activity of another app.